# expandablelistview does not exapnd in some mobile(like Sony xperia , htc mobile)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have created Expandable List view for some item to show , it works on samsung mobile but does not expand in sony xperia

here's my code below:

```
    ExpandableListView expListView;expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int prevoiusgrp = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            try {
                Group_position = groupPosition;
                if ((prevoiusgrp != -1) && (groupPosition != prevoiusgrp)) {
                    expListView.collapseGroup(prevoiusgrp);
                }
                prevoiusgrp = groupPosition;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



    });
```

this is the xml code:

`

```
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/categoryliastview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:childDivider="#800000"
            android:divider="@drawable/gradieant_background1"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:indicatorRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildIndicatorRight"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>`
```

this is expandableadapter method to expand parent and child

for parent

```
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, parent,
                false);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    ImageView groupindicator_icon = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.expendicon);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    if (isExpanded) {
        groupindicator_icon.setImageDrawable(_context.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.collapse));

    } else {
        groupindicator_icon.setImageDrawable(_context.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.expand));
    }

    return convertView;
}
```